# Xcode 8 - Auto Layout vs Flexible Section Headers (and Answer)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have `UITableViewCell` composed in a nib file. (But you could just use a prototype within a storyboard's `UITableView`.)

This cell is designed for use as a flexible-height Section Header:

Within its `contentView`, the cell contains a single `UIStackView`.  Inside the `UIStackView`, there are a bunch of `UILabels`, other stuff. The contents are variable, and dynamically added.

To make this happen:

1. add Constraints: pin the edges of the `UIStackView` to the `contentView`. Be careful not to use non-zero values for the constants here; otherwise Auto Layout may choke.
2. set `tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` to a positive non-zero value. This allows the height to be flexible.

After that, the usual: the nib is registered with the tableView, the cell is dequeued when needed, and its properties are set up.

Code generated in Xcode 7 and run on iOS 9 will now work. The cell (Section Header) height will change as you add/modify the contents of the Stack View.

**Problem:** Xcode 8 GM. The same layout generated through Xcode 8 and running on iOS 9 will fail. If you're lucky, Xcode may even give you some of those super-helpful "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" log messages that we adore so much.

Comment: You can answer your own question, but you should do so in the "answer" section.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry about that. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Xcode 8 and Auto Layout now need a UITableViewDelegate method to be implemented. It may be have been optional or inferred before, but no longer, so (if like me) you overlooked this, overlook it no more:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```